# How to obtain confidence interval with scipy in exponential distribution?

Tags: python, scipy, statistics

What is the correct way to obtain confidence interval with scipy in exponential distribution?

```
from scipy.stats import expon

conf_int = scipy.stats.expon.ttfs(0.95, loc=0, scale=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's clarify the usage of scipy.stats in general

1. if you say `from scipy.stats import expon` only the `expon` class will be available as `expon` in your namespace.
2. If you want to use `scipy.stats.expon` you would have to use `import scipy.stats` instead, that would make `scipy.stats` available for you and from there you can access any of its classes.
3. `expon` is a [rv_continuous](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.html), that is a generic interface to real valued continuous distributions. So you should stick to those methods, and apparently `ttfs` is not available.
4. Assuming that you want a centered 95% interval, what you need is quantile `2.5%` and the quantile `100%-2.5%=97.5%`
5. You can get any quantile using the percent point function [ppf](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.ppf.html#scipy.stats.rv_continuous.ppf), expressing your percentages as fractions of `100%`

Putting that together you should end up with a code as

```
from scipy.stats import expon
expon.ppf([0.025, 0.975], loc=0, scale=1)
```

```
array([0.02531781, 3.68887945])
```

You could also construct an instance of `expon` represented the parameterized distribution

```py
distribution = expon(loc=0, scale=1)
distribution.ppf([0.025, 0.975])
```

Or select a different location for the coefficient interval, e.g.

```py
expon.ppf([0.0, 0.95], loc=0, scale=1)
```

```
array([0.        , 2.99573227])
```

Answer (score 0):

The exponential distribution has a closed-form confidence interval [formula](https://books.google.com/books?id=mXP_UEiUo9wC&pg=PA267#v=onepage&q&f=false) for the rate parameter `lambda`. I think it's always important to think of CI relative to the parameter you care about or you’re simply just finding the quantile values for descriptive purposes.

With python, you can do something like this:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import chi2
from typing import Tuple

def ci_exp(sample: np.ndarray, alpha=0.05) -&gt; Tuple[float, float]:
    &quot;&quot;&quot;
    Finds the confidence interval for the rate parameter of an exponential  distribution.

    Parameters
    ----------
    samples : np.ndarray
        The sample of realized exponential random variables.
    alpha : float, optional
        The level of significance, by default 0.05.

    Returns
    -------
    Tuple[float, float]
        The lower and upper bounds of the confidence interval.
    &quot;&quot;&quot;
    n = len(sample)
    # MLE of lambda
    sample_mean = np.mean(sample)

    # Compute the sum of samples
    sample_sum = np.sum(sample)

    # The sample sum is gamma distributed
    gamma_shape = n
    gamma_scale = 1 / sample_mean

    chi2_df = 2 * n

    # Confidence interval for lambda
    lower_bound = (2 * sample_sum) / chi2.ppf(q=(1 - (alpha / 2)), df=chi2_df)
    upper_bound = (2 * sample_sum) / chi2.ppf(q=alpha / 2, df=chi2_df)
    ci = (lower_bound, upper_bound)

    return ci

if __name__ == &#39;__main__&#39;:
    sample = np.random.exponential(scale=1/0.5, size=100)
    ci = ci_exp(sample)
    print(ci)
```